# Error converting data type varchar to numeric in my SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote this stored procedure and tried to retrieve data. But I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure spMobileOperationsNew, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Can you help me to fix this issue?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMobileOperationsNew]
    @action AS nvarchar(50),
    @territorycode nvarchar(10) = '',
    @disYear  AS int = '',
    @disMonth AS nvarchar(10) = '',
    @territoryTarget AS decimal(18, 2) = '',
    @terDiscRate AS decimal(5, 2) = '',
    @maxDiscRate AS decimal(5, 2) = '',
    @minBill AS decimal(18, 2) = '',
    @allocateBudget AS decimal(18, 2) = '',
    @actualValue AS decimal(18, 2) = '',
    @actDiscValue AS decimal(18, 2) = '',
    @finalBudget AS decimal(18, 2) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@action = 'Get_TerritoryWiseTradeDiscount')
    BEGIN
        PRINT ('get territory')

        SELECT
            LTRIM(RTRIM(tt.[TerCode])) AS [TerCode], 
            tt.[Year], 
            (CASE tt.[Month] 
                 WHEN 'January' THEN 1 
                 WHEN 'February' THEN 2 
                 WHEN 'March' THEN 3 
                 WHEN 'April' THEN 4 
                 WHEN 'May' THEN 5 
                 WHEN 'June' THEN 6 
                 WHEN 'July' THEN 7 
                 WHEN 'August' THEN 8 
                 WHEN 'September' THEN 9
                 WHEN 'October' THEN 10 
                 WHEN 'November' THEN 11 
                 WHEN 'December' THEN 12 
             END) AS [Month], 
            tt.[MaxDiscRt], tt.[MinBillVal], tt.[TerTgt], 
            tt.[TerDiscRt], tt.[AllDiscBud], tt.[ActVal], 
            tt.[ActDiscVal], tt.[FinalDiscBudget]
        FROM
            TerritoryWiseTradeDiscount AS tt
        WHERE 
            tt.[TerCode] = @territorycode 
            AND tt.[Year] = @disYear 
            AND tt.[Month] = @disMonth
    END
END
```

When I execute this line

```
EXEC [dbo].[spMobileOperationsNew]'Get_TerritoryWiseTradeDiscount','KEG',2021,'November'
```

I get the error shown above.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You tried to use a string value as a number. Either you passed a string when a number was expected or tried to compare a numeric field with a string that doesn't contain a number.

Comment: Why are you using *strings* as default values for numeric types? What is `''` supposed to be? NULL or 0? Use the correct value instead

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server have a TRIM() function? I.e. do you really have to do LTRIM-RTRIM?

Comment: Yes I miss that basic thing, Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos,

Comment: Don't encourage lazy programming by providing nonsense default values for parameters.  Don't use PRINT to provide "information" to the procedure caller. And quite frankly - a procedure should do one thing. (Mis)using a parameter to make it do different things is a bad habit and poor design - read about [coupling and cohesion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/software-engineering-coupling-and-cohesion/)

Comment: And storing language-specific values for month is another poor choice. At a minimum, put that case logic into a computed column so you don't need to repeat it everywhere it is needed along with a constraint that prevents invalid month values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMobileOperationsNew]
@action as nvarchar(50),
@territorycode nvarchar(10)='',
@disYear  as int = '',---?????? may be 0
@disMonth as nvarchar(10)= '',
@territoryTarget as decimal(18,2) ='',---????? may be 0.00
@terDiscRate as  decimal(5,2) ='',--???? may be 0.00
@maxDiscRate as  decimal(5,2) ='',--may be 0.00
@minBill as  decimal(18,2) ='',--may be 0.00
@allocateBudget as  decimal(18,2) ='',--may be 0.00
@actualValue as  decimal(18,2) ='',--may be 0.00
@actDiscValue  as  decimal(18,2) ='',--may be 0.00
@finalBudget as  decimal(18,2) =''--may be 0.00
```